# Can't overwrite cookie

Tags: reactjs, cookies, nestjs

I ran into a problem and I can't solve it. The thing is that I implement the logic of the refresh token, and until the interception of the request with status 401 everything goes fine. But as soon as the 401 error appears, I have a request to the backend to refresh the token and the request remains pending. I checked the logic on the backend, everything returns there, but the token is not updated in the cookie. Please help me find the error.

**It's frontend axios interceptor**

```
import axios from 'axios'

axios.defaults.withCredentials = true

export const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_BACKEND,
})

instance.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
    return response
}, async function (error) {
    const originalRequest = error.config;
    if (error.response.status === 401 && !originalRequest._retry) {
        originalRequest._retry = true;
        await instance.get('auth/refresh-token', {withCredentials: true})
        return instance(originalRequest);
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

**It's backend code from auth service**

```
public async refreshTokenAuthenticate (payload: any, response: Response) {
    const access_token = await this.tokenService.generateRefreshToken(payload)
    return response.cookie('access_token', access_token, {httpOnly: true, secure: true})
  }
```